# Spring boot + Quartz + Oracle job scheduling

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, cron, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I want to schedule jobs using Quartz and Oracle as the JobStore. I see most of the examples using RAMjobstore (which is not persistent ofcourse) but hardly any that can help me with my requirement for Spring boot + Quartz + Oracle development.

Any links or help to code samples or github project  would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I could finally make a small working Spring boot + Quartz + Oracle JobStore application suiting my requirements! And I thought it might help to share links to others who are looking for the same.

I would suggest the below links and using these you can come up with a simple solution atleast:

1. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html
2. https://github.com/davidkiss/spring-boot-quartz-demo

For a persistent Jobstore (Specifically Oracle) please use the below properties in quartz.properties configuration file:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=spring-boot-quartz-demo
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 20
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=25000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false 
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS

#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:xxxxxxxx
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = username
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = password
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
```

The rest should be easy!! Cheers!